# My VLC player doesn't have minimize button

Tags: release-hera, vlc

[image]All my apps in elementary OS have a minimize button, but when it comes to VLC player, it doesn't have minimize button, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Tweaks do not really help, most windows follow the decoration (e.g., "minized on right" or "windows style") but several apps (VLC, SM PLayer, UM PLayer, Virtualbox, Teamviewer, DoubleCommander, Gigolo) don't.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the flatpak version of VLC along with OS X window controls and I have the minimize button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install Tweaks and check window controls in Appearance tab. On layout you can choose your style

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Hera in the AppCenter app look for "GNOME Tweaks" and install that.  After it downloads click open.  On the Window tab there is "Minimize" switch that you can flip on to show the minimize on the GNOME apps.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just click on the vlc icon on the dock which will minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the version from Synaptic (3.08) and it is okay.  I have in my notes to not install the one from Appcenter but I believe that was an issue unrelated to the OP's issue.